# W = Set of all functions such that f '(x) = x*f(x), determine whether it represents a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is a question from my lecture notes, but I was unable to follow what my teacher said. The exact question is:

Is the following subset of subspace in $C[a,b]$, the space of all continuous real-valued function on $[a,b]$? Let $W$ be the set of all differentiable functions such that $f'(x) = xf(x)$. I need to determine whether $W$ represents a vector subspace.

Comment: Maybe your teacher meant W =  Set of all __differerentiable__ functions such that f'(x) = x*f(x) ?

Comment: I have the exact lecture slide, it doesn't say so. But I'am pretty sure that's what he meant. Could you explain how it's true?

Comment: To check whether $W$ is a vector subspace, you should check whether it contains the $0$ vector (in this case, the $0$ function) and whether it is closed under (pointwise) addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zero function is a constnat function so it's derivative is zero, therefore it holds
$f'(x)=x.f(x)$ $\forall x$ $\Rightarrow$ $0\in W$.
Let $f,g \in W \\$.
We have $(f+g)'(x)=f'(x)+g'(x)=x.f(x)+x.g(x)=x.(f+g)(x)\\$
Therefore $(f+g)\in W.\\$
Let $f\in W$ and $a=const$.
Then $(af)'(x)=a.f'(x)=a.x.f(x)=x(af)(x)\Rightarrow af\in W.\\$

So it follows that $W$ is a vector space.

Answer (score 0):

if $f'(x) = xf(x)$ must $f(x)$ be a continuous function?  Are all functions in $W$ also in $C[a,b]$

Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions in $W,$  is $f(x) + g(x)$ in $W$?

That is, given $f'(x) = xf(x)$ and $g'(x) = xg(x),$ does $\frac {d}{dx} (f(x) + g(x)) = x(f(x) + g(x))$ ?

For all constants $c$ is $cf(x)$ in $W$?

Does $\frac {d}{dx} (cf(x)) = x(cf(x))$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If  $W$ = Set of all differerentiable functions such that $f'(x) = x*f(x)$, you have to prove that $W$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. So let $f,g\in W$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have to show $h:=\alpha f+  \beta g \in W$.
Since $f,g$ are differerentiable so is $h:=\alpha f+  \beta g $
So we have 
$$ h'(x) = (\alpha f(x)+  \beta g(x))' = \alpha f'(x)+  \beta g'(x) \\
 =\alpha x f(x)+  \beta x g(x) \\
=x (\alpha f(x)+  \beta g(x)) \\
= x h(x) $$

So $h \in W$ and we are done.

The bottom line is  $W$ is a subspace, because differerentiation of functions is linear.

Answer (score 0):

This is overblown solution, but you might proceed as follows:

we have differential equation $f\prime(x) = xf(x)$. It can be shown, that the only solution is ($C$ is some real number):
$$
f(x) = C\cdot e^{\frac 1 2 x^2}
$$
Now, obviously $W$ is a vector subspace - it is exactly the set of real multiples of $e^{\frac 1 2 x^2}$, $\text{span}(e^{\frac 1 2 x^2})$.